# OAuth2RestTemplate is getting a new token with every request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-integration, spring-security-oauth2

We are using Spring Security with Oauth2 in a Spring Integration project, and we use this approach in an outbound-gateway.

By default this Oaut2RestTemplate is getting a new token every time it makes a request ?

If not, how do we have to manage the refresh ?

This is our code :

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="aisleDataToOSPGateway"
request-channel="aisleDataToOSPChannel"
rest-template="oauth2RestTemplate"
url="${osp.aisle.rest.url}/{id}"
http-method="PUT"
expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
header-mapper="headerMapper"
reply-channel="ospRestAisleOutputChannel">
<int-http:uri-variable name="id" expression="headers['AISLE_ID']" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>


@EnableOAuth2Client
@Configuration
public class RipOauth2Config {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.client")
    public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails() {
        return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(clientCredentialsResourceDetails);
        template.setRetryBadAccessTokens(true);
        template.setErrorHandler(new OspResponseErrorHandler(clientCredentialsResourceDetails));
        return template;
    }
}
```